# How to get rid of this line?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a very specific issue.

**# Conditions**

- Internet Explorer | Edge
- On a certain size

An image will explain it:
[image: Bottom line]

I am using CSS mentioned below on a absolute positioned triangle to create an arrow effect. The image is visible in the triangle and this solution is the only responsive one I could find.

However, in IE, a bottom line is showing?
This seems to be ONLY in IE (as usual)

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abayob/jf9e4mh0/7/) to test this issue, but the issue only shows in the fiddle when you vertically resize the container the HTML is in.

The CSS of the arrow looks as following:

```
.image_text .arrow {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   padding-bottom:25px;
   background-color: #ffffff;
}
.image_text .arrow:before, .arrow:after {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  padding-bottom:inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
}
.image_text .arrow:before {
  right: 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -ms-transform: skewX(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewX(45deg);
  transform: skewX(45deg);
}
.image_text .arrow:after {
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -ms-transform: skewX(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-45deg);
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
}
```

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: Fx, Chr and Edge give slightly different results for me. The tip of the feather(leaf?) and its right are different + distance between tagline and top of feather/leaf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not so sure about this, but usually IE have some problem with such issues and adds extra space in the elements.

You can try using

> bottom: -1px;

for the **.image_text .arrow** class

Answer (score 1):

Tough to remove it altogether considering IE rendering usual trips, I'd suggest masking it with a white `border`, (`bottom: -1px;` will not solve it, at least on my end), may not be what you want, but visually does the trick:

- Add `border: 1px solid white;` to `.image_text .arrow`

**[---> External Fiddle <---](https://jsfiddle.net/Syden/jf9e4mh0/10/)**

Previews:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I really like your idea, but the one of @Abhishek is more usable, because I don't have to concern about the color.
Still a good solution though!